# Type hinting. How to hint that object passed to a function must have some method/attribute access?

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-hinting

please, see an example which uses numpy doctstring for type hinting:

```py
def my_function(obj):
    """Do some work.

    Parameters
    ----------
        obj : Any class with `do_work()` method
    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    time.sleep(5)
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to tell a caller that function expects object which has `do_work` method? Is there a way to specify such type hints using `python3`/mypy type hinting or/and numpy docstrings?

Comment: it seems that you have invalid tags, python-2.7 has no syntax support for type annotations

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov

Python-2.7 has docstrings and thus have numpy styled docstrings. Which is used for typehinting by Pycharm for python2 versions. Let alone things like `mypy` and `typing` module backport to python2 which implements type annotations

Comment: accepted answer uses syntax that is not supported by Python2.7 that's all I'm saying

Comment: @AzatIbrakov no, you're saying that question has invalid tags. Accepted answer can be used with mypy in python 2.7 without any problems (although with typing_extensions package) And my guess is that i would also have zero problems if i implemented my own typeshed file in pycharm using accepted andswer syntax. And that's what makes accepted answer also valid for python 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

```
import typing


class Worker(typing.Protocol):
    def do_work(self):
        pass


class SomeWorker:
    def do_work(self):
        print("Working...")


def my_function(obj: Worker):
    obj.do_work()


x = SomeWorker()
my_function(x)  # This will type check; `SomeWorker` doesn't have to inherit from Worker
```